# What keyboard shortcut is there to organize C# usings in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, refactoring

Is there a way to organize C# usings (remove and sort, in separate or together) via a shortcut in Visual Studio for one or more files of a project?

I know that this can be done via the menu for one file by selecting

`Edit > IntelliSense > Organize Usings > Remove and Sort`

but I want to do this much faster.
I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express for *C#* development (wondering how this can be done in older & other versions too though). Thank you in advance.

Comment: since VS2017, use `Ctrl-R + Ctrl-G`

Comment: Here is a thread for solutions for VS 2019 https://stackoverflow.com/q/55615136/6300406

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Go to Tools => Options => Environment => Keyboard

[image]

Enter the key combination you want to use (click the **Press shortcut keys:** textbox, press your key combo as you would execute it while editing)

[image]

Then type "usings" in the **Show commands containing:** textbox

[image]

And now you can assign whichever version of these remove/sort usings commands that you like to the key combination.

This works for pretty much every command in Visual Studio, and from any addons you have installed.  Just type a word involved in the command name to find the command.  Assign away!

Comment: If you have Ctrl + F assigned to Edit.Find like the default Visual Studio shortcut, assigning Ctrl + F, Ctrl + U to a using action will remove the find shortcut. If you face this problem, just pick another combination of keys that are not already used as a single key action.

Comment: As of Visual studio 2017, I can't find any command containing `using`. 

However, two commands exist: `Edit.RemoveAndSort` and `EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.RemoveAndSort` which both clean up the usings. 

The latter has already a keyboard shortcut which is `Ctrl + R, G` for me, with the default keyboard mapping.

Comment: Odd they would deprecate commands like that, but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 107):

Since VS2017, it's a builtin shortcut. Simply press **Ctrl + R, Ctrl + G**. Credit goes to Emanuel Ve, who mentioned this first in the comments; I'm putting the advice into an answer for greater visibility.

Comment: Thank you! Is there an entry in the menus somewhere too?

Comment: How do I apply this to all C# code files, solution wide ?

Comment: Can I configure this somehow on how to sort? It is alphabetically but stylecop sometimes brings SA-1208 https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1208.md with some usings that I have. So I will manually move the System.* to the front and would love to have that automatically done by this command.

Comment: Doesn't work in .razor files

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Will's answer,
[Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace)
is a great addon that has all this - and lots lots more!

[image]

Comment: The question is for a shortcut... how can the context menus above be made to appear? Thanks.

Comment: @track0 when you install the addon detailed in the above answer you can right click the project or a file in it to have it appear. i bet you can also create a short cut for it, but haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Productivity Power Tools no longer work since VS 2019 16.9.4.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> organizes all the lines