# In Visual Studio 2019 how can I remove unused usings on format document?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019 how can I remove unused usings on format document?

I have found instructions for previous versions of Visual Studio (Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting.). I don't see that in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: In VS2017 it is labelled "Experiment" which generally means it may not survive... (I usually just use Crtl-R,Ctrl-G which is mapped to the context menu comment to sort & remove usings).

Comment: You can use using organization on save [like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55905851/6725736)

Answer (score 67):

In Visual Studio 2019 you can remove unused usings with the **Code Cleanup** command:

[image]

[image]

And running code cleanup also formats the document.

Comment: What have happened to the CTRL + K + D shortcut that would this also?

Comment: @DanielLobo Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D still formats document.

Comment: @DanielLobo that is where .NET Framework got it wrong. Moving this to a different command abides by the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: I'm with OP on this one - I really enjoyed having a single command to do both. It seems like the code cleanup should be configurable to also format the document. Given that code cleanup is already configurable, that seems like it would have hit both camps.

Comment: It didn't when I tried before but maybe I'd jacked something up. I'll give it another go.

[edited to add] - it looks like the thing I was expecting it to do it just doesn't do generally, so that's on me.

Answer (score 48):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> will sort and remove your unused `using`s.

Answer (score 16):

First :  go Extensions - > install "Productivity Power tools"  then "Power Commands for Visual Studio" extentsion

Second : go tools menu -> Options -> Productivity Power tools -> PowerCommands -> General -> checked "Remove and Sort Usings on save"

**note** : These options are available only when you use "Power Commands for Visual Studio".

Comment: These options are available only when you use "Power Commands for Visual Studio". Please, mention this in your answer.

Comment: @KyryloM Thanks.  I reformatted my computer and couldn't figure out why this had stopped working.  I didn't realize this wasn't a part of Power Tools.  So glad I saw your comment!

Comment: I am using VS 2022, I installed Productivity Power tools, but didn't find "Remove and Sort Usings on save" neither  "Power Commands for Visual Studio"

Answer (score 8):

The keyboard command that works for me is [image: Edit.RemoveAndSort]

Comment: Hi @SuitBoyApps, I tried to include a picture but StackOverflow wouldn't let me embed it due to not having enough reputation. The submission form even forced me to use and then replaced my embedded image with the link provided. So I'm at a bit of a chicken and egg problem here. I'm sure it's been a while since you were posting under an account that had no reputation so I'm sure you wouldn't have known this. I'll leave it as is, thanks.

Comment: I did not realize it was a picture. I went ahead and added it for you.

Answer (score 7):

We can remove it by clicking on the light bulb and selecting" Remove Unnecessary Usings". In addition to removing it from the current document, if we closely look at the bottom of the popup, it can be done for the Project or Solution as well. No need to install or configure anything. This feature is available on VS2015, VS2017, VS2019 and VS2022 on my machine.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I always use the combination **CTRL + R, CTRL + G**. This sorts the usings and removes the unused ones.

Answer (score 6):

**For single page** :

> `Ctrl+K+E`

**For all projects**:

1. **Right click** to your **solution** on your Solution.
2. Click on **Analyze and Code Cleanup** followed by **Run Code Cleanup (Profile 1)**
   [image]
3. And all done, it cleans and formats all over the project.
4. **If you need some more setting on code cleanup or if it don't work** you need to click on **configure code cleanup** below **cleanup profile**.
5. And then add necessary settings.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can assign both functions to Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D by changing hotkeys and keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call it by hand, you can use '**cleanup on save**' 
[see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55905851/6725736)