# How do I stop Visual Studio from adding random usings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, using

I think this is VS (not VS Code) trying to be helpful - it auto-adds a `using` whenever it thinks I need one.

However, in current C# most usings are not needed, I only expect to see one or two on most files.

Edit a file in Visual Studio for 20 mins and I suddenly have 15, and they'll all random. Not completely invalid, but often from the more obscure dependencies that aren't relevant to the class I'm working on (often referenced in the same solution but not a dependency of the project, even indirectly).

For instance, I'll type `public Parser GetParser(...` and (even though `Parser.cs` is a file next to this one and in the same namespace) VS will add `using VendorLibrary.LegacyFormats.UsedInOneObscurePlace.Parsers;`.

This is annoying, and either gets picked up in the PR review (*"why do you have 15 usings here?"*) or a build exception (`Parser` is ambiguous between `CurrentProjectNamespace.Parser` and `VendorLibrary.LegacyFormats.UsedInOneObscurePlace.Parsers.Parser`).

This affects everyone on my team, not just me.

Anyone know what causes this and how I can stop it?

Comment: Go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> Expand `Text Editor` -> `C#` -> Select `Intellisense` -> Uncheck `Show items from unimported namespaces`. This should prevent completion (and subsequent addition of `using`)

Comment: Related (though not *really* a duplicate): [In Visual Studio 2019 how can I remove unused usings on format document?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55615136/10871073)

Comment: Maybe the next C# standard will have a `not using` statement?

Comment: Especially its causing *ambiguous types* bites me from time to time and it is really annoying.

Comment: I too see this a lot, and it seems to have gotten a lot worse since I started using Co-Pilot, which does make sense as Co-Pilot occasionally comes up with outlandish suggestions for code solutions, and dismissing that code does not seem to also clean up the using list.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen any idea how to get it back to how it used to work? i.e. intellisense autocomplete would find it, but add a red underline, and then `CTRL+.` would pop up the choice of fixes (including both namespace prefix and using imports for every possible namespace).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError we have a mix of copilot users on the team and everyone has the problem (even those without it).